# Query that brings the most occurrences of a certain field in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I have the following query :

```
$top_cont = DB::table('quests') 
       ->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfDay(), Carbon::now()->endOfDay()])  
       ->take(5)
       ->get();
```

The `quests` table has a `user_id` column. I'm trying to get the top 5 `user_id`s who have the most contributions (i.e. has the most number of rows in the quests table for this day).

How can I adjust the query to bring the `user_id`s that have the most occurrences ?

If someone can do it in raw sql, this will be helpful too.

Comment: `SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) FROM quests WHERE created_at >= date(NOW()) AND created_at < date_add(date(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY) GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$top_cont = DB::table('quests') 
    ->select('user_id', DB::raw('count(*) as contributions'))
    ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', now()->startOfDay()) 
    ->take(5)
    ->groupBy('user_id')
    ->orderBy('contributions', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

This should give you 5 records with this form:

```
dd($top_cont);
```

> ```
> => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3403
>      all: [
>        {#256
>          user_id: 2,
>          contributions: 51,
>        },
>        {#3417
>          user_id: 975,
>          contributions: 50,
>        },
>        {#3418
>          user_id: 743,
>          contributions: 46,
>        },
>        {#3419
>          user_id: 538,
>          contributions: 45,
>        },
>        {#3420
>          user_id: 435,
>          contributions: 18,
>        },
>      ],
>    }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following query:

```
    DB::table('quests') 
       ->whereBetween('created_at', [ Carbon::now()->startOfDay(),Carbon::now()->endOfDay()])
        ->select('user_id', DB::raw('count(*) as count') )
        ->groupBy('user_id')
        ->limit(5)
        ->orderBy ( 'count  DESC')
        ->get();
```